# Make Aurelia checkbox binding use 1\0 instead of true\false

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to bind input type checkbox to a single variable, checkbox should be checked when variable has value `1` and unchecked if it is `0` or `null`.
When user clicks checkbox - variable should become `1` when checked and `0` when unchecked.

Which is the proper way of doing such binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that Aurelia way of doing this is to use value converter, especially when there are many places where you need to convert `1`\`0` to `true`\`false`:

```js
export class BooleanValueConverter {
  toView(value, trueValue = 1, falseValue = 0) {
    return value === trueValue
  }

  fromView(boolean, trueValue = 1, falseValue = 0) {
    return boolean ? trueValue : falseValue;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked.bind="oneOrZeroProp | boolean">
```

This converter will work with other values for `true` and `false` as well:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked.bind="yesOrNoStringProp | boolean:'yes':'no'">
```

Answer (score 2):

Aurelia binding for checkboxes supports booleans or arrays of objects, numbers or strings.
A standard way would be to use a boolean observable property and map its value changes to the number (0 or 1) variable:

```js
import { observable } from "aurelia-framework";

export class App {
  @observable trueOrFalse: boolean = false;
  oneOrZero: number = 0;

  trueOrFalseChanged(newValue: boolean) {
    this.oneOrZero = this.trueOrFalse ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="trueOrFalse" />
    Checkbox
  </label>
  Value: ${oneOrZero}
</template>
```

For a working example, please see: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-germain-5n3iy?file=/src/app.html:0-136)

Comment: Nice solution, but will not work if `oneOrZero` property is inside object inside array, and input type checkbox is created using `repeat.for` on top of that array.

Answer (score 1):

checked.bind="varName === 1"

and listen for click to modify varName
click.delegate="setVarName()"

setVarName () {
varName = varName ? 0 : 1;
)